# What is equivalent to local folder(magento1) in magento2 to override third party template file

Tags: magento2, extensions, overrides

The file path is `/app/code/Third partsparty/itsMoDULE/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` and I want to override this. I created the same file in `app/design/frontend/MyTheme/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/` but still reads from third party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override path should be

app/design/frontend/MyTheme/theme/Thirdpartsparty_itsMoDULE/templates/product/list.phtml

`Thirdpartsparty_itsMoDULE` is module name you can check that name from **registration.php** of that module.

module related files are place in `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName`

theme related files are place in `app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName`